# Removing all empty elements from an character array

Tags: java, sockets

I have a character array that can hold maximum 50000 characters at a time. Contents of this array are coming through socket connections. However it is not guaranteed that this character buffer is not going to have any empty elements. Then I need to convert this character array into a String (e.g. new String(buffer);). My question is, whenever I receive a buffer from socket that is not 50000 long, how do you remove left over or empty elements from this char array or this String? If not, what is the most efficient way you would suggest?

/*Here is the current implementation*/

```
private BufferedReader is;

//Other code    

public String readBufferUpdate() throws IOException {
    char[] buffer =new char[50000];
    is.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

////// This is an implementation using ByteArrayOutputStream

```
public String readAuth() throws IOException {
        int s;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((s = is.read()) != -1) {
            bao.write(s);
            if (!is.ready())
                break;
        }
        if (s == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        String result = bao.toString();
        return result;
    }
```

This implementation is extremely slow when I need to read huge amount of data.

-----------------edit

(for example, server sends me data but it might not always be 50000 long bytes but 32822 long bytes then I need to remove left over array elements)

Comment: Why are you reading it into an array, read it directly into the string?

Comment: I cannot use .readLine() function for this. I have to use is.read() and assign contents to an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to read from an `InputStream` in a buffer is as follows.

```
public String readBufferUpdate() throws IOException {
    char[] buffer =new char[50000];
    int bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    return new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Here you `is.read()` returns how many bytes have been read into `bytesRead`. Only that many bytes are copied from the buffer to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

something like that should work too :

```
public String readBufferUpdate() throws IOException {
  char[] buffer =new char[50000];
  is.read(buffer);

  return new String(ArrayUtils.removeElements(buffer, ''));
}
```

Doc here : 
[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#removeElements(char[], char...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#removeElements%28char%5B%5D,%20char...%29)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest converting the array to a string and using the replaceAll and trim functions to remove the empty elements.

```
String bufferString = new String(buffer).trim().replaceAll(" ", "");
```

This does not require any additional libraries.

Comment: Using the replaceAll method makes the trim method redundant by the way.

Comment: It does not make it redundant - trim removed from the ends where the replaceAll will remove from inside the char[] as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, encoding);
String theString = writer.toString();
```

OR

```
String theString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -1):

use an array list instead! This wil allow you to remove array elements, whereas the standard array package has no 'easy' way of doing this.

ArrayList  buffer = new ArrayList (50000)

buffer.add(x)

buffer.remove(x)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Note: instantiate a type on the ArrayList