# Better ways than BufferedReader.readLine()?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Using `ServerSocket` and `BufferedReader.readLine()` the input is only read once the line is terminated on the client side, is there anyway to read the input, and send an output before the line is terminated?

```
ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(35553);
while(true){
    Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
    InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

    String MESSAGE = BR.readLine();

    PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println(MESSAGE);
    PS.print("Returned Successfully");
}
```

Comment: How is the data sent? Is it buffered on the client side?

Comment: @dacwe that's the part that I don't know, all I know is the data is received on the server as the client terminates the line.

Comment: @user2186161 just a suggestion according to java code conventions variable follow something like sentence case ie first letter of a new word is capitalised in the case of twoworded variable. you can use eg:ServerSocket serverSocket  = new ServerSocket(35553); instead of all capital variables afterall it is good to follow code conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with `bufferedReader.read()` which will return the values one character at a time

```
StringBuffer response = "";    

while ((c = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) 
{
        //Since c is an integer, cast it to a char. If it isn't -1, it will be in the correct range of char.
        response.append( (char)c ) ;  
}
```

If you go with this method, it's up to you to figure out when you can start parsing the result and send a reply.

Comment: I am not good at char, the response.append says _The method append(char) is undefined for the type String_. Is response a String?

Comment: it should be (see definition in example)

Comment: I did realise i forgot to capitalise `String`

Comment: You need a `StringBuffer` not a `String`, after this code do `StringBuffer.toString()` to get the String.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405968/removing-all-empty-elements-from-an-character-array/15406675#15406675)** answer.

You can read input into a buffer whose size is under your control.

(Apologies if linking to self answers is considered bad. Felt like reusing it. We are devs after all.)

Comment: It is definitely not bad to link to existing answers! If it is yours or not doesn't matter as long as it is contributive to the actual question.