# Faster input style in java

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

Scanner has a method hasNext() but if i want to use BufferedReader insteadOf Scanner how to handle hasNext() types of method in BufferedReader?
I want to do this because BufferedReader is faster than Scanner. Is there any faster input reading way besides BufferedReader? 
Need Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is throwing up a bunch of red flags for me. How is Scanner to slow for you? Have you profiled your code to demonstrate that the Scanner object is your definite bottleneck? What are you trying to read in? How is the data to be read in structured? How are you trying to parse things? How is the current code slowing things down? Please clarify your question by providing the important details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Strings use a `StringBuilder`. It is a built in object in Java and allows you to not have to recreate a String every time you append a String.

I have not worked with a scanner much because I like `BufferedReader` so much. Java's `BufferedReader` reads a certain amount of bytes at a time. The default buffer size is 8192 characters. You can change this is you want to if you think you will be reading enormous amounts of characters. An integer as the second parameter would specify the number of bytes to read each time.

This is how you would use a BufferedReader and StringBuilder efficiently:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String output;

    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/lotsOfText.txt"), 8192)) { //if you want a bigger buffer - give it a larger number
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n"); //StringBuilder returns a reference to itself
        }

    } catch (IOException io) {
            System.err.println(io.toString());
    }

    output = sb.toString();

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

If you are expecting double or ints, you can use a `try{}catch (Exception e){}` and in the try use either java's class `Double` or `Integer` to parse a string:

```
try {
    double d = Double.parse(line);
    int i = Integer.parse(line);
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.err.println(nfe.toString() + "\n\nThe number was unreadable");
}
```

Your question was really vague, so it is hard to give you an explicit answer. I hope this helps.

Also, as a note, `BufferedReader` also accepts an `InputStreamReader` as an argument, so you could have

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) {} catch...
```

in order to read user input.

The "truly" correct way to read an `InputStream` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405968/removing-all-empty-elements-from-an-character-array/15406675#15406675)

Comment: In case you were wondering, I copied and pasted the Constitution of the United States 1000 times exactly (with two new lines between each transcript) to the text file "lotsOfText.txt" on my Desktop, and it ran in less than a second (without printing it to standard output, of course) - and this is a pretty crappy computer that takes almost four minutes to boot up. With `System.out.println(output);` it took a loooong time (over a minute) to run, but that is because **that** takes a long time - not the `BufferedReader`.